# Not able to set state in react properly

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I'm new to react and trying to make form with Material UI. Below is the sample of code that I have tried. The form is rendering correctly on first load but when I tried to change the select element it shows me error. Can someone please point out what i am doing wrong please. The error showing that 
values.service_category.map is not a function.

```
const service_category = [
    {
        value: "service one",
        id: "1"
    },
    {
        value: "service two",
        id: "2"
    }

];

function getServices() {
    return service_category.filter(g => g);
}

class ServiceRequestForm extends Component {

    state = {
        step: 1,
        service_category: [],
        service_req_date: '',
        data: [
            {
                full_name: '',
                address_one: '',
            }
        ],

        hasError: false
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const service_category = getServices();
        this.setState({ service_category })

    }

    handleChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        });
    }

    render() {        
        const { step } = this.state;
        const { service_category } = this.state;
        const values = { service_category };

        switch (step) {
            case 1:
                return (
                    <ServiceCategoryForm
                        nextStep={this.nextStep}
                        handleChange={this.handleChange}
                        values={values}
                    />
                );

              // Some other form  based on switch case.        
        }
    }
}

export default ServiceRequestForm;


export default class ServiceCategoryForm extends Component {

    render() {

      const { handleChange, values } = this.props;

        return (

            <div style={{ marginTop: '100px' }}>

                <h4>Select service you want</h4>

                <form>
                    <FormControl error={hasError}>

                        <Select
                            value={values}

                            onChange={handleChange}
                            inputProps={{name: "service_category"}}

                        >
                            <MenuItem value="">
                                <em>Select Category</em>
                            </MenuItem>
                            {
                                values.service_category.map((value, id) =>{

                                    return  <MenuItem value={value.value} key={id}>{value.value}</MenuItem>;
                                })
                            }

                        </Select>
                        <FormHelperText>Please select service category</FormHelperText>

                    </FormControl>
                </form>                
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating an object like this,

```
const values = { service_category };
```

you just need simple assignment like,

```
const values = service_category ;
```

Second thing is your iteration is wrong, you need to do this,

```
{
  values.map(value =>{
    return  <MenuItem value={value.value} key={value.id}>{value.value}</MenuItem>
  })
}
```

Another important thing is, your `select` has name `service_category` and you have `onChange` handler for the same.

```
handleChange = (event) => {
   this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
   });
}
```

Above code will change your original state `service_category` with just a selected value and you will not able to see any other option in your `select` after re-render.

**You must change name of `select`.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Replace

```
values.service_category.map((value, id)
```

To:

```
values && values.service_category.map((value, id)
```

Comment: Try : values && values.map((value, id)

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of errors here.

You are wrapping `service_category` in an `object`

```
const { service_category } = this.state;
const values = { service_category }; <--
```

Just pass `service_category` as the `values prop` from `ServiceRequestForm` to `ServiceCategoryForm`

```
const { service_category } = this.state;

return (
  <ServiceCategoryForm
    values={service_category}
  />
);
```

Then in `ServiceCategoryForm` iterate over `values`

```
{values.map(({ value, id }) => (
  <MenuItem value={value} key={id}> 
    {value}
  </MenuItem>
))}
```

Now what's causing the crash after you pick an item is that you set `this.state.service_category` to the selected value in `handleChange` through `e.target.name`

You will need to change the name to something like `chosenCategory` and also add it in your state and changing `inputProps name property`.

[Working SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-sara-0qfbk)

Comment: Thank you. Its working fine. Now the scenario is very clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

First you can replace

```
function getServices() {
    return service_category.filter(g => g);
}
```

with

```
function getServices() {
    return service_category;
}
```

and in the `render` of `ServiceRequestForm`
instead of 
    `const values = { service_category };` it is being wrapped in `object`

you can do `const values = service_category;`

Answer (score 0):

replace this:

`const values = { service_category}`,

with this one

`const values = [ ...service_category ]`